# Connection to the Jupyter Notebook Server could not be established

Tags: python, powershell, server, jupyter-notebook, kernel

For the past many months I am trying to code in Jupyter Notebook but whenever I open Jupyter Notebook, then, I see a message where it is written 'A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.'

I ran Juypter Notebook in both normal way and in Administrator in powershell but then also, it did not worked.

I even uninstalled Jupyter Notebook and reinstalled it again.

The thing which I see when I first open Jupyter Notebook:-

[image: kernel connecting]

The image showing 'kernel connection failed'

[image: failed to connect jupyter notebook server]

Answer (score 2):

Downgrading the tornado package solved this problem for me.

conda uninstall tornado

conda install tornado==5.1.1

Answer (score 2):

On my Win 10 install / Python 3.8.3rc1 / tornado 6.1 I was starting Jupyter-labs.exe from a  command prompt, it was exiting and bringing up the error : A connection to the Jupyter server could not be established. :

Running the Command Prompt as Admin or starting Jupyter-labs-exe from powershell corrected the issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

With python = 3.8 this option does not work.
This option does not work with python 3.8 Specifications:

```
   - tornado == 5.1.1 -> python [version = '> = 2.7, <2.8.0a0 |> = 3.5, <3.6.0a0 |> = 3.6, <3.7.0a0 |> = 3.7, <3.8.0a0' .
```

How could I switch to python 3.7, without affecting the rest of the Anaconda3 package that installed python 3.8 for me?

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me also and I've tried everything. The thing is that you don't have to close the powershell (or cmd) window while you are working in the jupyter notebook, because the cmd or the powershell **IS** the kernel.

https://www.dummies.com/programming/python/interacting-kernel-python-programming/

Answer (score -1):

This worked well for me. Changed the Terminal to run on Rosetta.

https://medium.com/thinknum/how-to-install-python-under-rosetta-2-f98c0865e012

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32247389)